# How to make collectible change its animation on collision with player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my first question here and I'm a total newbie. I have made an item that can be picked up by the player on collision and it simply resets the player animation (not my point here) and I just wanted the sprite of the pickup to change before it destroys itself.

I have searched around but I couldn't find anything for this.

Here's my current code on the pickup:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class PickUpReCharge : MonoBehaviour {
   public Animator anim;
   public Animator animc;

   void Start() {
   }

   void Update() {
 }

 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
   if (other.tag == "Player") {
     anim.Rebind();
     animc.Rebind();
     Destroy(gameObject);
    }
  } 
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I tried to use something like transitioning to a different animation state where the pickup animation occurs, the object destroys itself before the animation plays and just doesn't look right.

This is what I tried to do first:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpReCharge : MonoBehaviour {

  public Animator anim;
  public Animator animc;
  public Animator animp;

  void Start() {

  }

  void Update() {

  }

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

   if (other.tag == "Player") {
     anim.Rebind();
     animc.Rebind();
     animp.Play("Pickup", 0, 0.0f);
     Destroy(gameObject);
    }
  } 
}
```

But it didn't work at all.

I'm looking for an effect kind of like when sparkles appear after you pick up a coin for example.

Is there any premade asset that I can reference from maybe? Or is the code an easy one and I'm just that bad at coding lol?

Thanks ^^

Comment: There are many ways to do this, you could use `Destroy(gameObject,0.5f)` to destroy the `gameObject` after 0.5 seconds. Or you could use a Coroutine, that waits for some time and then destroys the `gameObject` and does whatever else you wnat it to do. You could also use animation events, whatever suits you best

Comment: This works well! I didn't know about the time function in destroy.gameObject! Thanks. I want to mark you as the answer but I don't know how. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of the user Ali Baba.

Basically, I take the `Destroy(gameObject);` and add time to it. `Destroy(gameObject, 0.3f);`

This adds a delay to the destruction of the object.

This made it work for me. So I placed my animation script in there and it had enough time to play!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpReCharge : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public Animator animc;
    public Animator anime;

    void Start()
    {
        anime.Play("Pickup", 0, 0f);
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            anim.Rebind();
            animc.Rebind();
            anime.Rebind();
            Destroy(gameObject, 0.3f);
        }
    }
}
```